# Onto and one to one function from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ be the function $f(n) = r n + b$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb Z$. Prove or disprove:

3) if $f$ is onto then $r=1$ or $r=-1$

4) if $r=1$ or $r=-1$ then $f$ is onto

As for number $3$ and $4$, I'm not sure how to go about them. I know what onto means but I'm not sure if these are true and false.

Please help

Thank you!

Comment: Your proofs for $1$ and $2$ seem fine. The idea behind the next two is like this: if I give you any integer $k$, can you find me an $n$ such that $f(n) = k$? That is $rn + b = k \implies rn = k-b$. But recall that $n$ is an integer, so $(k-b)/r$ needs to be one as well, for every $k$.

Comment: yes $\quad \quad$

Comment: What about number 3? I'm not sure if can find an r such that f is onto and r does not equal 1 or -1 as a counter example

Comment: try the contrapositive: if $r\neq \pm 1$ then can you find a $k$ such that $f(n)$ can never be $k$?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think so.

Comment: Take $k = b+1$ then $f(n) = rn + b = b+1 \iff rn = 1$ which isn't possible if $r \neq \pm 1$.

Comment: if r was not 1 or -1 I can never be sure that n is an integer

Comment: Ohh. I think I get it. It is true then. How do you suggest I go about writing the proof ?

Answer (score 1):

3) is true. Let $f$ be onto we want to prove $r \in \{ -1 , 1\}$ 
choose any two elements  $x , y \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(x,y) = 1 $ greatest common divisor between them is one. Since $f$ is onto there exits $n_1, n_2$ such that

$f(n_1) = x \rightarrow rn_1 +b = x$

$f(n_2) = y \rightarrow rn_2 + b = y$

$b = x - rn_1 , b = y - rn_2 $ hence $(y-x) = r(n_2 - n_1)$ thus $r \mid (y-x)$ but $(x,y) =1 $ therefore $r = 1 $ or $r =-1$

4) Also true. If $r=1$ let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $(m-b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(m-b) = 1(m-b) + b = m$. If $r=-1$ choose $b-m$, $f(b-m) = -(b-m) + b = m$

Answer (score 0):

Since we've cleared up $Q4$ in the comments, then I'll only address $Q3$: we use the contrapositive. If $r \neq \pm 1$ then $rn \neq \pm 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So $rn + b \neq b \pm 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $f$ is not a surjection.

Comment: So this is like proof by contradiction?

Comment: No. Contraposition, just like how you proved 2).

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how you concluded that f is not onto from the last line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like $(1)$ and $(2)$ are pretty solid.

For part $(3),$ note that if $f$ is onto, there is an $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $rn_1+b=1$ and $rn_2+b=0.$ Solve this system of equations for $r,$ use your results from the first two parts to infer what number $n_1-n_2$ cannot equal, and then recall that $r$ must be an integer. What are the only possible choices for $r?$

For part $(4),$ let $m$ be any integer and let $r=1.$ If we set up $rn+b=m$ that means $n+b=m$ and so $n=m-b.$ To what set of numbers does $n$ belong in every one of these cases? Repeat this exercise assuming $r=-1$ for a similar result.